# Cannot insert values with checking conditions in SQL

Tags: sql

i need to insert values into a table but after it checks the condition so please help me

thanks in advance

```
insert into b (SELECT userID,username, ANSWERTOQUESTION1 AS AnswerToQuestion  From a 

UNION ALL 

SELECT userID,username, AnswerToQuestion2 AS aswertoquestion  From a)
```

i need to insert values into b table if it is not there.
that means all the values in the table should be compared so that i can insert the value

Comment: what conditions u have ?? & choose any one of tagged DBMS

Comment: Can you describe your problem with more details? We can't help you if you don't give us more details, eg. put your query here.

Comment: Do you need this for Oracle, MySQL or for SQL.server ? You can not have all three of this tags!

Answer (score 0):

My unserstanding, you wanted to insert the records into B table from A that not in B, so at the end B table will have all the values that are in A.

If that is true,

i hope this below will help

```
Insert into B
Select userid, username, answertoquestion1 from a
minus
Select userid, username, answertoquestion1 from b;
```

Thanks
Thangamani Eraniyan

Comment: Dear Thangamani  thanks for ur support but the column name varies for answertoquestion

Comment: if you don't mind can you send me table structure? I can see the column name "answertoquestion2" in table a? do you still want to compare with answertoquestion1 from b? if yes, just change the column name.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into b 
select t2.userID,t2.username,concat(t2.AnswerToQuestion1,t2.AnswerToQuestion2) 
from a as t2 
LEFT JOIN b t3 on t3.userID=t2.userID;
```

To avoid duplicate record,use below query:

```
INSERT INTO b 
SELECT t2.userID,t2.username,concat(t2.AnswerToQuestion1,t2.AnswerToQuestion2)  
FROM a AS t2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM b AS t3 WHERE t2.userID = t3.userID);
```

Comment: @yogesh, edited the query,pls check now and accept the answer if it is relevant to your question